# Webpack ProvidePlugin import before CSS Modules?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

I'm using Webpack's ProvidePlugin to auto-import common components such as a `<Button />` component. I'm also using CSS Modules. A typical component might look like:

```
import styles from './Component.scss';

export default function Component() {
  return <Button className={styles.btn} />
}
```

This works 99% of the time. But I noticed that if I try to override `Button`'s styles in the first imported component that uses `Button`, the styles don't override without `!important`. It overrides if I manually import `Button` above the `Component.scss` import. It seems like ProvidePlugin is importing `Button` below `Component.scss`.

In other words, ProvidePlugin is equivalent to:

```
import styles from './Component.scss';
import Button from 'components/Button';
```

But I'd like it to be:

```
import Button from 'components/Button';
import styles from './Component.scss';
```

In the second example, the CSS order is correct. Is it possible to do this with ProvidePlugin or another Webpack plugin?